# HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, conda, miniconda

After a clean install of python 3.7.11 with miniconda, tried to install pandas but failed:

```
(base) C:\Users\jisib>conda install pandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
```

I'm quite new to python so likely a very basic error :). anaconda.com is not blocked
(https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json isn't either)

Tried creating an environment first but also failed:

```
(base) C:\Users\jisib>conda create --name myenv2022_03
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This seems like a general networking problem. Are you able to connect to other HTTP servers like Google etc?

Comment: This could be the issue. Google and other services work fine in https. Maybe something is forcing me to have https and blocks http connections? (Is that your question?). I'm not sure how to validate that hypothesis and where to change such settings.

Comment: Can you connect with Curl / wget?

Comment: "C:\Users\jisib>curl https://www.anaconda.com" works wget as well

Comment: The one it actually complains about is `https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json`

Comment: Good catch. C:\Users\jisib>curl https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json works.

Comment: You omitted the `https`, does `curl https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json` also work?

Comment: Yes it does work with https. but the "conda install pandas" doesn't. Still don't understand how to solve this.

Comment: Can you show us the result of running `conda -v install pandas` ?

Comment: This is the result: usage: conda-script.py [-h] [-V] command ...
conda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -v

Answer (score 4):

Just copy these:-

> libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

> libssl-1_1-x64.dll

from
C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin to C:\Anaconda3\DLLs.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Sadly it did not work: (base) C:\Users\jisib>conda install pandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: - An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network team.
'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'

Comment: It also **does not work** for me. In my case I copy both files from `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin` to `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs`.

Answer (score 2):

the error comes from new SSL policy.

To ignore SSL verification and try to install pandas

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

or
Anaconda Prompt

```
set SSL_NO_VERIFY=1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sadly it did not work: (base) C:\Users\jisib>conda install pandasCollecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.
'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'

Comment: can you try to ping **repo.anaconda.com**  with package addresses (104.16.131.3 or 104.16.130.3) @Bernard

Comment: As none of the answers here have solved the OP's problem, but I'm required to award the bounty to one of the answers it received, I'm picking this one as the most promising one in terms of further investigation in my admittedly limited understanding of the problem.

Comment: Ping seems to work: ping repo.anaconda.com

Pinging repo.anaconda.com [2606:4700::6810:8303] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 2606:4700::6810:8303: time=22ms
Reply from 2606:4700::6810:8303: time=25ms
Reply from 2606:4700::6810:8303: time=16ms
Reply from 2606:4700::6810:8303: time=16ms

Ping statistics for 2606:4700::6810:8303:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 25ms, Average = 19ms

Answer (score 0):

For me, removing the environment variable `SSLKEYLOGFILE` on Windows worked.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the pip installer, or installing using the Anaconda Prompt? To install using pip, after creating the virtual environment, open a terminal console and try that:

```
source activate [name of virtual environment]
pip install pandas
```

Comment: Pip is intalled and not working either: (base) C:\Users\jisib>pip --version
pip 21.2.4 from C:\Users\jisib\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

Comment: Maby try manual way: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/pandas/

Comment: Since I have miniconda instead of anaconda, I don't think I have the Navigator interface mentioned in your documentation. (At least I tried and failed yesterday :) )